# Fusion reactor with lasers and magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, laser, fusion

Both magnetic and laser fusion reactor work to a point, but what would happen if you had magnets and then lasers to heat up the pelts and/or plasma? And what would be the best the best way to achieve such a machine? The magnets would compress the plasma and the lasers would heat up the plasma: would this work? Would it create something else? Or would it just be a lost cause (although maybe it would still be something that would help advance the prototypes that are being build today)?.

Thanks for any and all information.

Comment: as far as I'm aware, the method used in tokamaks at the moment is inducing a current through a central coil to heat up the plasma to its final temperature so I'm not quite sure what you're asking

Comment: so bear with me cause I'm try not to reveal my design but trying to figure out a theory of how it would work.

Comment: but you would have  rings that would compress the plasma but then you would have lasers that would ignite and heat up the pellet. so you would drop a pellet inside of the rings and the lasers would ignite the pellet and then the rings  would compress the plasma all into the center so that it would hold together and heat up to the temperatures to fuse the atoms together to the point where you could turn off the lasers and only need the rings to hold the fusion atom in place.

Comment: so my question is would this have a possibility in advancing our knowledge about how to achieve nuclear fusion? what kind of force would be needed to compress the plasma to create a stable fuse? what kind of electronic measuring machine would be needed to measure the heat, electrostatic, radioactivity, cameras, and other gadgets? and would there be more abundant atoms to put together the hydrogen, deuterium-tritium? and would like adding 5 different partials be better for creating fusion or would the reaction become to violent and create something that would be deadly? thanks for the info.

Comment: I'd ask the nay-sayers here to take a step back.  This might be difficult, and it may sound unreasonable, but what do you think of a fusion program in which the first energy to the grid is predicted for around 2070, and then only one plant?  (ITER/DEMO)   There is at least [one company](http://www.helionenergy.com/?page_id=199) working on magnetic compression of pellets, and it's not outrageous to suggest zapping it with a laser.  Furthermore, in EUV photolithography, molten tin pellets are zapped at a rate of 100,000 per second.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, your question basically is *can we combine the magnetic confinement fusion concept with laser heating of pellets?*

I would say no, because I guess it would be quite difficult to hit your pellet after it has entered the tokamak (or stellarator) plasma (and you better be sure to hit it instead of hitting the vessel wall). And then, why would you want to do that at all? The idea of magnetically confined plasmas is that the temperature and confinement time is large enough to achieve fusion in a sustained way (i.e. the heat of the fusion products is used to keep the fusion reaction going).

Attaching some very high power lasers to a tokamak would not help to achieve a positive power balance.

Answer (score 0):

The question really is about the feasibility and usefulness of combining magnetic confinement with laser heating in order to achieve thermonuclear fusion.

Most magnetic confinement systems (like Tokomaks) use RF heating because it is efficient in that context, and laser heating would be very inefficient.  Most inertial confinement systems use laser heating because it is possible to focus lasers onto a fuel pellet and efficiently heat the pellet.

So the question can be narrowed down: Would it make sense to combine magnetic confinement with inertial confinement?  It might make sense, and you can be sure that it has been considered. There is an alternative approach to fusion which sends a huge pulse of electric current through a small metal tube filled with fuel.  The current pulse induces a magnetic field pulse that compresses the tube and fuel, and also heats the resulting plasma.  Using a giant laser pulse to add more heat with controlled distribution and timing could (possibly but not certainly) make that approach work better.

Comment: The  set up difficulties of high power lasers can be seen here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afGEs_Xjcwg

Comment: Twenty-some years ago I got a look at the Lawrence Livermore laser-driven inertial confinement system.  The laser was big enough to fill a basketball stadium.  Certainly not a practical system.  The beam intensity was so high that a dust speck on a meter-wide lens (costing many tens of thousands of dollars) was enough to destroy the lens.